# Import and run things in one off Clojure script

Tags: clojure

I'm new to Clojure and I've been following the tutorial here: http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/clojure-web-application

So I've been running my apps with `foreman start` and then testing small Clojure scripts with `lein repl`.

However running sequences of interactions in the `REPL` is time-consuming and frustrating; I'd like to put all the interactions in `lein repl` in a one-off script that I can run all the way through.

The following two lines work when run from `lein repl` (after calling, for example, `lein deps` with a `project.clj` file), but not when I put them in a file called `interactions.clj` and try running the file with `clj interactions.clj`.

```
(use 'clojure.contrib.http.agent)
(string (http-agent "http://jsonip.com/"))
```

What do I need to do to be able to run those two lines (and more) from a one-off script?

I tried using `lein run interactions.clj`, checking the instructions on importing things [here](http://howthefuckdoiimportthingsinclojure.pen.io/) (and trying out twenty different versions of ns, :use, :require and '), and `lein oneoff interactions.clj` with no success. It shouldn't be that hard to do this, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I want

```
java -cp /path/to/clojure-1.X.X.jar:path/to/other/deps clojure.main -i /path/to/scratchfile.clj
```

Answer (score 2):

This isn't exactly what you're asking for, but I usually create a runnable jar file as explained here: http://zef.me/2470/building-clojure-projects-with-leiningen.